# Why select statement always return the last inserted values?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

When I try to Select a record using Prepared Statement it always giving me a last inserted values that I recently add.

First what did I do is to search a record in my first table. If the record is exist the foreign key table will populate the values. My Primary and Foreign Key tables works well. The values populating appropriately to their corresponding components but it's not giving me the right values. Any help?

[image: 1st Table]

This is the Primary Key table referencing Foreign Key table which is the 2nd table.

[image: 2nd Table]

**Select Query:**

```
String searchSECTIONNAME = "SELECT * FROM allsections_list WHERE SECTION_NAME = ?";//1st Select Statement

String searchSECTIONSETTINGS = "SELECT allsections_list.`SECTION_ID`, allsections_settings.ADVISER_ASSIGNED, allsections_settings.SECTION_POPULIMIT,\n" +
    "allsections_settings.ROOM_ASSGN, allsections_settings.YRLEVEL_ASSGN, allsections_settings.SCHOOL_YEAR, allsections_settings.SESSION_ASSIGNED\n" +
    "FROM allsections_list\n" +
    "RIGHT JOIN allsections_settings\n" +
    "ON allsections_list.`SECTION_ID`=allsections_settings.`SECTION_ID`";//2nd Select Statement
```

So what did I do here is join the `SECTION_NAME` column to Foreign Key table using ***Right Join***. If the record exist it will join the two tables.

**Code:**

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String searchSection = Section_SearchSection_Textfield.getText();


    try (Connection myConn = DBUtil.connect();
         PreparedStatement myFirstPs = myConn.prepareStatement(searchSECTIONNAME);)
        {
            myFirstPs.setString(1, searchSection);

         try (ResultSet myFirstRs = myFirstPs.executeQuery())
         {
             int resultCounter = 0;
             while (myFirstRs.next())
             {
                 String mySectionName = myFirstRs.getString(2);//Get the value of SECTION_NAME
                 Section_SectionName_TextField.setText(mySectionName);
                 Section_SectionName_TextField.setEnabled(true);

                 try (PreparedStatement mySecondPs = myConn.prepareStatement(searchSECTIONSETTINGS))
                 {
                    try (ResultSet mySecondRs = mySecondPs.executeQuery())
                    {
                        while (mySecondRs.next())
                        {
                            String myAdviserAssigned = mySecondRs.getString(2);
                            Section_Student_Limit_ComboBox1.setSelectedItem(myAdviserAssigned);
                            Section_Student_Limit_ComboBox1.setEnabled(true);

                            String mySectionPopulation = mySecondRs.getString(3);
                            Section_Student_Limit_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(mySectionPopulation);
                            Section_Student_Limit_ComboBox.setEnabled(true);

                            String myRoomAssigned = mySecondRs.getString(4);
                            Section_Room_Assignment_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myRoomAssigned);
                            Section_Room_Assignment_ComboBox.setEnabled(true);

                            String myYearLevelAssigned = mySecondRs.getString(5);
                            Section_Session_Level_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myYearLevelAssigned);
                            Section_Session_Level_ComboBox.setEnabled(true);

                            String mySchoolYear = mySecondRs.getString(6);
                            Section_SchooYear_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(mySchoolYear);
                            Section_SchooYear_ComboBox.setEnabled(true);

                            String mySessionAssigned = mySecondRs.getString(7);
                            Section_Session_Settings_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(mySessionAssigned);
                            Section_Session_Settings_ComboBox.setEnabled(true);

                            resultCounter++;

                        }//end of loop mySecondRs (ResultSet)
                    }//end of try mySecondRs (ResultSet)
                 }//end of try mySecondPs (PreparedStatement)

             }//end of loop myFirstRs (ResultSet)
             if (resultCounter == 1)//If exist
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Found");
             }
             else//If not exist
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Data Found");
         }//end of try myFirstRs (ResultSet)

    }//end of try myFirstPs (PreparedStatement)

        catch (SQLException e) 
        { 
            DBUtil.processException(e);
        }//end of catch
}
```

As you can see here. In my first **ResultSet** `myFirstRs` when I search a existing `SECTION_NAME` the foreign key values will populate. If something something in my loop correct me. Thanks in advanced!

**Update!**

I add a ORDER BY clause in my 2nd Select Query. Because without this the database will return what it wants, so what did I do is modify the query and add the ORDER BY clause like this:

```
String searchSECTIONSETTINGS = "SELECT allsections_list.`SECTION_ID`, allsections_settings.ADVISER_ASSIGNED, allsections_settings.SECTION_POPULIMIT,\n" +
    "allsections_settings.ROOM_ASSGN, allsections_settings.YRLEVEL_ASSGN, allsections_settings.SCHOOL_YEAR, allsections_settings.SESSION_ASSIGNED\n" +
    "FROM allsections_list\n" +
    "RIGHT JOIN allsections_settings\n" +
    "ON allsections_list.`SECTION_ID` = allsections_settings.`SECTION_ID`" +
    "ORDER BY allsections_list.SECTION_ID";
```

Still giving me wrong values when I run the project. I tried to run this in NetBeans query and giving me a values in a ASC order.

[image]

Comment: Why do you only check if `resultCounter == 1` instead of `> 0`?

Comment: @callyalater When I used `resultCounter > 0` still giving me a last values. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a simplest solution. I joined the two tables using Right Join.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String searchSection = Section_SearchSection_Textfield.getText().replace("!", "!!").replace("%", "!%").replace("_", "!_")
   .replace("[", "![");

    String searchSECTIONSETTINGS = "SELECT allsections_list.SECTION_ID as 'ID', allsections_list.SECTION_NAME as 'Section Name', allsections_settings.ADVISER_ASSIGNED as 'Adviser', allsections_settings.SECTION_POPULIMIT as 'Population',\n" +
    "allsections_settings.ROOM_ASSGN as 'Room', allsections_settings.YRLEVEL_ASSGN as 'Year Level', allsections_settings.SCHOOL_YEAR as 'School Year', allsections_settings.SESSION_ASSIGNED as 'Session'\n" +
    "FROM allsections_list\n" +
    "RIGHT JOIN allsections_settings\n" +
    "ON allsections_list.SECTION_ID = allsections_settings.SECTION_ID\n" +
    "WHERE SECTION_NAME LIKE ? ESCAPE '!'\n" +
    "ORDER BY allsections_list.SECTION_ID";

    if (searchSection.isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up this fields");
    }
    else 
        try (Connection myConn = DBUtil.connect();
         PreparedStatement myFirstPs = myConn.prepareStatement(searchSECTIONSETTINGS);)
        {
              myFirstPs.setString(1, "%" +searchSection +"%");
         try (ResultSet myFirstRs = myFirstPs.executeQuery())
         {
             int resultCounter = 0;
             while (myFirstRs.next())
             {
                 String name = myFirstRs.getString(2);
                 sectionJTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(myFirstRs));
                 resultCounter++;
             }//end of loop myFirstRs (ResultSet)

             if (resultCounter > 0)//If exist
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Found");
             }
             else//If not exist
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Data Found");
         }//end of try myFirstRs (ResultSet)

    }//end of try myFirstPs (PreparedStatement)

        catch (SQLException e) 
        { 
            DBUtil.processException(e);
        }//end of catch
}
```